# C# Inheritance / Interfaces

Tags: c#

I have a class `Item` that is inherited by other classes... `Attraction`, `Business`, `CommunityEvent`.  I cannot set the object `items` the way that I am, it is a syntax error.  The Lists can't be assigned like this.  What is the best way to go about doing this?  Basically, Attraction is an item, but it has a few more properties.  Business is an item, but it has a few more properties.  ...etc.

```
public List<Item> GetItems(PageType type)
    {
        List<Item> items;

        switch (type)
        {
            case PageType.Attraction:
                items = new List<Attraction>();
                break;
            case PageType.Business:
            case PageType.ShopAndEat:
                items = new List<Business>();
                break;
            case PageType.Event:
                items = new List<CommunityEvent>();
                break;
            default:
                items = new List<Item>();
                break;
        }

        // TODO: Call Webservice method to get Item



        return items;
    }
```

Comment: You could make items an IEnumerable<Item> and return an IEnumerable<Item>.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be able to use generics and type restrictions to do some of the heavy lifting for you.  How about

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sample
{
    public class Item
    {
    }

    public class Business : Item
    {
    }

    public class Attraction : Item
    {
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public List<T> GetItems<T>() where T : Item
        {
            //TODO: based on T, call the appropriate services to populate the list
            return new List<T>();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Examples:
            var foo = new Foo();
            List<Attraction> attractions = foo.GetItems<Attraction>();
            List<Business> businesses = foo.GetItems<Business>();
            List<Item> items = foo.GetItems<Item>();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Actually populating the list with objects that have a few more properties than `Item` (and accessing those properties) will take you pretty quickly into Co- and Contravariant generics.  I would highly recommend Eric Lippert's excellent [blog series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/) on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do

```
items = new List<Business>();
```

You can do

```
items = new List<Item>();
```

and still add different kinds of items to the items list like

```
items.Add(new Business());
```

Your items list can be all different kinds of items.